# My phone seems like it is sending MMS messages, but they never actually arrive - what's going on?

Tags: mms

There are several MMS problem threads on here, but none seem to get at the issue I'm having. I can receive MMS messages just fine, however I cannot send them. What is bizarre is that, from all indications, the phone *thinks* they are being sent. I get no error message and it even attaches a timestamp to the message. How can I find out what's going wrong and correct it?

Potentially necessary details:

- Phone: Samsung Galaxy SII
- OS version: 4.0.4
- Network: Credo (via Sprint)
- MMS app: Default Android app; I did briefly switch to using Facebook Messenger but recently switched back

Comment: Are you charged for them? You might wish to contact your provider with that, maybe they're stuck with them.

Comment: I don't think so, I've got one of those unlimited all-in-one packages.

Comment: OK, so you probably don't see them on your bill. Still, I'd contact the carrier with this issue, they can surely check their logs, or even do a "live check". Meanwhile, you could check with a `logcat` tool (e.g. [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)) what's going on: Start aLogCat, clear log, hit "play" to have it recording. Send a MMS, wait for its "OK". REturn to aLogCat, press pause, export the recorded log to your sdcard (to have it save). Now check the recording for everything that might be related to your MMS.

Comment: I find aLogCat impossible to use; you almost have to have insider information into what the developers decided to call things in order to have any luck finding things, especially given the number of stuff it collects. It'd take a whole day of tinkering to solve it that way and I simply don't have that kind of time to spend on the problem.

Comment: So rather do some try-and-err, and see where it leads? :) You still could post the saved log to e.g. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link it from here, so we could take a look and point things out. But without hard facts, it's difficult to assist you.

Comment: That's an excellent point. I might do that!